# Finding index of left and right element's index of null in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I'm trying to use simple linear interpolation to replace any nulls in my data array.
I need to find left and right values in order to get the linear interpolation calculation.
I've coded this following,

```
const data = [null, null, 537309, 514619, 548638, 618428, 615091, 695349, 828929, 925076, 741585, 650574, 730432, 795618, 997527, 1112017, 1137697, 1231562, 1210135, 1204056, 1252409, 1261298, 1230198, 1336902, 1420173, 1502653, 1553030, 1514224, 1397548, 1353077, 1336532, 1250078, 1274630, 1231772, 1295328, 1249025, null, 1394515, null, null];

let result = [];
let i=1;
let j=1;
let before;
let after;

data.forEach((elem,index)=>{
    if(elem === null || typeof elem !=="number"){
         const condition = !Object.is(null, data3[before]) && !Object.is(null, data3[after])
         do {
         i = i +1;
         j = j +1;
         after = index + j;
         before = index - i;
         result.push({before:before, index:index,after:after})
         } while (!condition);
  }
})
console.log(result)
[
  { before: -2, index: 0, after: 2 },
  { before: -2, index: 1, after: 4 },
  { before: 32, index: 36, after: 40 },
  { before: 33, index: 38, after: 43 },
  { before: 33, index: 39, after: 45 }
]
```

As you can see, there are some elements that would return me undefined if I put it back to data.
such as  `data[-2]`, `data[43]` and `data[45]` would return `undefined`.
But I'll be calling this whole function recursively so that each null will be replaced by utilizing previously calculated output.

Expected Output should be the two nearest indexes from null index within the range of data:

```
[
  { before: 2, index: 0, after: 3 },
  { before: 0, index: 1, after: 2 },
  { before: 35, index: 36, after: 37 },
  { before: 36, index: 38, after: 37 },
  { before: 37, index: 39, after: 38 }
]
```

Here you can test linear interpolation https://dmytropaduchak.github.io/simple-interpolation-example/#linear
and examples from https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-linear-interpolation

```
const points = [{ x: 1, y: 1}, { x: 2, y: 2 }];
const calculate = linearInterpolation(points);

calculate({ x: 1.5 }); // y -> 1.5
calculate({ y: 1.5 }); // x -> 1.5
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output. What do you want to happen with the `null` values at the extreme ends of the array? There you cannot use interpolation...

Comment: You will alsso need to specify the expected behavior in the case where we have several consecutive null values (because we don't want all of those to take on the same value right ?)

Comment: I've just edited the post please leave any questions if I answered inappropriately. I just want to make sure that If there are null data in my data array, I want to replace those nulls using simple-linear-interpolation. If those null are not available to replace with it, then just keep it null at this point.